# Duplicating content roots detected

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, build.gradle

I've a multiple modules project with a shared folder which I want to add to the classpath of all sub-modules

so in my build.gradle I added

```
subprojects {

  apply plugin: 'java'
  //...

  sourceSets {
        main {
            resources {
                srcDirs += [
                        "$rootDir/shared"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Intellij idea shows me this warning and added a log

> 2021-06-29 11:22:34,124 [67203620]   WARN - .manage.ContentRootDataService - Path [/Users/xxx/Dev/my-project/shared] of module [my-project-boot.module-1.main] was removed from modules [my-project-boot.module-2.main, my-project-boot.module-3.main, my-project-boot.module-4.main, my-project-boot.module-5.main]

Any idea for how to remove this warning ? or it's just a bug of intellij ?

Comment: This feature isn't supported anymore. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72358843/sharedtest-got-warning-duplicate-content-root-detected-on-android-studio-chipm

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SharedTest got warning "Duplicate content root detected" on Android Studio Chipmunk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72358843/sharedtest-got-warning-duplicate-content-root-detected-on-android-studio-chipm)